Chrome deletes cookies even after Secure and SameSite=none
I'm having a problem with deploying my website. Everything worked in development but now I'm moving to production for the first time, hosting my backend on fly.io and my frontend on vercel. I'm running into this weird issue with my jwt cookie where it just disappears... I have checked on postman and it indeed returns my jwt cookie but it won't work on my website.
I tried to pinpoint the problem and commented out my redirects so I can see what's happening.. Turns out, the jwts come back fine! then I go to any other page and my auth middleware doesn't go successfully and I get redirected by my frontend back to the login page... Apparently chrome is doing something with the cookies so I saw some other posts about setting sameSite:'None' and secure:true and tried those but it didn't work. Also!! I have tried adding this "domain: '.drew-book-jo6x-f97k35gp8-andrew-marabantes-projects.vercel.app'," to my cookie but it just glitched my res.cookie to not send anything..
Here's some of my code :
Backend Cookie Function:
const loginUser = (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.find({ username: username })
        .then(async (user) => {
            if (user.length === 0) {
                res.json('Wrong Username')
            } else {
                 if (!user[0].password) {
                     return res.json('google')
                }
                const hashedPass = user[0].password
                const match = await auth.bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPass);
                if (!match) {
                    res.json('Wrong Password!')
                } else {
                    const accessToken = auth.jwt.sign({ userId: user[0]._id },       process.env.SECRET, { expiresIn: '10m' });
                    res.cookie('jwt', accessToken, { httpOnly: true, path: '/', sameSite: 'None', secure: true })
                    return res.json('success')

                }
            }
        })
        .catch(err => res.json('Error'))

}
FrontEnd:
essentially, the front end is just GET fetch calls in a use-effect that fire on mount, passing the jwt in the credentials, you don't want to see all that.
I suspect that chrome is deleting my cookies but I'm so new to deploying that I don't know if it could be a vercel or fly.io thing. Please help! Thanks

I guess it was a CORS problem... adding this to my fetches worked out but is really bad for security reasons:
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',

